# Next.js and Sanity Live Preview not working

Tags: next.js, live-preview

I’ve been stuck on this for days. I’ve followed a sanity guide for the pages router and also for the app router, but regardless of following them, live preview will not work. Instead of it updating as content is entered, I have to refresh multiple times before the changes are shown. I don’t understand why this is happening and I feel like I shouldn’t be having this much trouble. Every dependency im using is up to date.

I followed the provided next.js guides on sanity’s website.